# How to use cherrypy test harness for my own application?

Tags: python, testing, cherrypy

I can find the [way to call the test harness](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/Testing), but I can't figure out how to write a simple test case.  Thanks.

Comment: http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/RestfulAuth has some useful example code, but something with some helpful explanations would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got a simple test case working, but since we are using a non-standard routing method I discovered that I had to reinitialize the global cherrypy configuration explicitly for each test case (after the testharness reinitializes it incorrectly).  Here it is:

"""
test that the test harness is working.
"""

```
import test_assignment_web
from cherrypy.test import helper
import cherrypy

class testTestHarness(helper.CPWebCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # fix up the cherrypy tree...
        test_assignment_web.setUp()
    def testTestPage(self):
        path = "/test"
        self.getPage(path)
        self.assertStatus('200 OK')
```

test_assignment_web.setUp() fixes up the cherrypy "tree" object to work after the testharness breaks it.  This test case works for me with the TestHarness as described in the link given in the question.